# Self-healing SslStream

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I'm writing a service that needs to maintain a long running SSL connection to a remote server. I need this server to be self-healing, that is if it's disconnected for any reason then the next time it's written to it will reconnect. I've tried this:

```
bool isConnected = client.Connected && client.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectWrite) && stream.CanWrite;

if (!isConnected )
{
    this.connected = false;
    GetConnection();
}

stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Flush();
```

But I find it doesn't act as I would expect it. If I simulate a network outage by disabling my wifi, I'm still able to write to the stream with stream.Write() for approximately 20 seconds. Then next time I try to write to it, none of client.Connected, client.Client.Poll(), or stream.CanWrite() return false, but when I go to write to the stream I get a socket exception. Finally, if I try to recreate the connection, I get this exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I would appreciate any help create a long running SslStream that can withstand network failure. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use a SslStream, can you use a higher layer abstraction like WCF which has those robustness features built in?

Comment: I don't own the server side of the equation, so I cannot change to anything other than SSL.

Comment: When the connection is cut, you don't know what was received and what wasn't. Restarting will be harder than you think. TCP does not preserve message boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying protocol for SSL is TCP. TCP will usually only send data if the application wants it to deliver data, or if it needs to reply to data received from the other side by sending an ACK. This means, that a broken connection like a lost link will not be noticed until you are trying to send any data. But you will not notice immediatly, because:

- A write to the socket will only deliver the data to the OS kernel and return success if this delivery was successful.
- The kernel will then try to deliver the data to the peer and will wait for the ACK from the client.
- If it does not get any ACK it will retry again to deliver the data and only after some unsuccessful retries the kernel will declare the connection broken.
- Only after the connection is marked broken by the kernel the next write or read will return the error from kernel to user space, like with returning `EPIPE` when doing a write.

This means, if you want to know up-front if the connection is still alive you have to make sure that you get a regular data exchange on the connection. At the TCP level you might set TCP_KEEPALIVE, but this might use an interval of some hours between exchanges packets. At the SSL layer you might try to use the infamous heartbeat extension, but most peers will not understand it. The last choice is to implement some kind of heartbeat in your own application.

As for the self healing: When reconnecting you get a new TCP connection and you also need to do a full SSL handshake, because the last SSL connection was not cleanly closed and thus cannot be resumed. The server has no idea that this new connection is just a continuation of the old one so you have to implement some kind of meta-connection spanning multiple TCP connections inside your application layer on both client and server. Inside this meta-connection you need to have your own data tracking to detect, which data are really accepted from the peer and which were only send but never explicitly accepted because the connection broke. Sound like a kind of TCP on top of TCP.

Answer (score 3):

From a 10.000 feet point of view:

The reason you can still write to the stream after shutting down your wifi is because there is a network buffer that is holding the data for transmission, stream.Write/stream.Flush success means the network interface (TCP/IP stack) has accepted the data and has been buffered for transmission, not that the data has reach its target.

It takes time to the TCP/IP Stack to notice a full media disconnection, (connection lost/reset) because even if there is no physical link TCP/IP will see this as a temporary issue in the network and will keep retrying for a while (the network could be dropping packets at some point and the stack will keep retrying)

If you think about this in the reverse way, you won't like all your programs to fail if there is a network hiccup (this happen too often on internet), so TCP/IP takes its time to notify to the app layer that the connection has become invalid (after retry several times and wait a reasonable amount of time)

You can always reconnect to the server when the SslStream fails and continue sending data, although you will find is not as easy as this because there are several scenarios where you send and data is not received by server and others where server receive the data and you do not receive any ACK from server at all... So depending on your needs, self-healing alone could be not enough.

Self-Healing is simple to implement, data consistency and reliability is harder and usually requires the server to be ready to support some kind of reliable messaging mechanism to ensure all data has been sent and received.